# Is it allowed/does it make sense to ask a question on more than one StackExchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, stack-exchange, software-engineering-se, cross-posting

I have a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212504/implementing-in-house-flexible-scheduling-solution-based-on-cron-and-periodic-pa), and I am not sure which site is more suitable (**StackOverflow** or **Programmers**).

I've tried to read the about it and haven't found a conclusive answer.

Is it allowed/does it make sense to ask a question on more than one StackExchange site?

Comment: Don't cross post. If something is suitable to two (or more) sites, try to think where, conceptually, it is a better fit and ask there. We can always migrate a question if needed.

Comment: Now, if a question posted on the wrong site was not migrated but summarily closed, can we post a duplicate on another more appropriate site, or is this question (and others like it) forever doomed to oblivion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the others stated, no, don't cross post. Each site has a specific area that it covers. For instance, [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/about) stackexchange site covers conceptual questions about software development. This is where your questions belongs. [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about) is more meant for specific programming problems. I admit, it's easy to get confused but thoroughly reading their about pages clear things up.

Worse comes to worse it gets migrated. If you feel like you posted in the wrong area, ask a moderator to migrate it (flag it, click other, and ask to move it to another site) or delete your questions and re-post it.

Comment: I understand why not to cross post. Ideally each site have it's own domain, but practically, it isn't always so.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but each question usually has a main focus. For instance, your question _"Does this solution covers most of possible schedule requests?"_ seems more fit for programmers.stackexchange.com since it's more conceptual. You don't seem to be having issues getting your code to work.

Answer (score 3):

No. Ask on the site that feels better suitable, and if people there will tell you it's not, request migration.